filter swagger documentation according to controller
I want to filter the swagger documentation according to controller name.Is there any swagger endpoint i can access where i can provide the controller name and it will filter the documentation to only show the documentation of the apis in the said controller.Additionally is it possible for me to build an api in springboot to do this task,if so how do i configure this.Every time i hit this api i want the swagger-ui to refresh and only show the filtered documentation.
I have tried implementating this api ,but it does not seem to work.This is my configuration class

@Configuration
@RefreshScope
public class OpenApiConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DocumentationService filterService;// Default filter

    @Bean
    public OpenApiCustomizer controllerFilterCustomizer() {
        return openApi -> {
            String filterCriteria = filterService.getFilterCriteria();
            Paths paths = openApi.getPaths();
            Paths filteredPaths = new Paths();

            paths.forEach((path, pathItem) -> {
                if (shouldIncludePath(pathItem,filterCriteria)) {
                    filteredPaths.addPathItem(path, pathItem);
                }
            });

            openApi.setPaths(filteredPaths);
        };
    }

    private boolean shouldIncludePath(PathItem pathItem, String filterCriteria) {
        return pathItem.readOperations().stream()
                .anyMatch(operation -> operation.getTags().contains(filterCriteria));
    }
}


this is the service class,


@Service
@RefreshScope
public class DocumentationService {

    private String filterCriteria = "userController";

    public String getFilterCriteria() {
        return filterCriteria;
    }

    public void setFilterCriteria(String filterCriteria) {
        this.filterCriteria = filterCriteria;
    }
}

and this is the endpoint


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/documentation")
@Tag(name="documentationController")
public class DocumentationController {

    @Autowired
    private DocumentationService filterService;

    @Autowired`your text`
    private ContextRefresher contextRefresher;

    @PostMapping("/setFilter")
    public void setFilterCriteria(@RequestParam String criteria) {
        filterService.setFilterCriteria(criteria);
        contextRefresher.refresh();
    }
}

this will only filter the documentation according to the default criteria which is the user controller,when i hit this api it does not do anything
